# Rails Generate CRUD without scaffolding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am taking a Ruby on Rails course and I have reached a point where we are creating users and the views with them. The instructor ran "rake routes" and had all the CRUD for users with routes already generated, however when I ran "rake routes" i got just the users#create. Somewhere down the line mine did not generate all the crud actions and routes with them. I will be creating my controller actions from scratch no problem, and I will have to add my routes by hand it seems.

Is there a better way to generate the crud with routes without scaffolding for future issues if this occurs again?

Comment: try resources :users in your roues file.

Comment: can you share ur scaffold command? Basically it should have all of the CRUD generated. Do you have resources :users in your gemfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding resources to your routes file automatically generates CRUD routes you want. [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) is the guide in rails guides. But still you must create views and actions by hand.